# Can I use classes in native Node.js?

Tags: node.js, class, electron

I want to develop my first Electron app, and somehow the book that I'm reading gave me the impression that I can't use classes in a native Node.js setting, and I must use transpilers for that. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You got a wrong impression. You can use classes without any transpilers. There was a time when you couldn't, but [starting from NodeJS version 6](https://node.green/#ES2015-functions-class), that is not the case anymore.